# Capture a city of wild spirits by humans without an arms battle? They can be attracted to a vessel they will attach/feel drawn to and stop resisting

Tags: magic, science-fiction, mythical-creatures, religion

I need to attack a city under the control of evil spirits to take back control. Since the enemy are spirits, physical or arms warfare will not help. Since spirits are shown to exist, magic is available. However, using too much magic will raise an alarm to the dark lord who is connected to the spirits but at a distance. The spirits are like mercenaries for the Dark lord and are wild and unstable.

I want to achieve it through a sneak attack but one which focuses not on a fight but on putting the spirits to sleep or hallucinates them so that they cannot relay the true scenario to the dark lord. In this manner, the Dark lord stays connected to them but does not know what is happening on the ground before it's too late.

How do I tame the unstable and dangerous spirits or put them under sleep?

Any spiritual healing process to soothe the spirits to the point of sleep, or magical spell that does not use too much energy but puts wild and huge energy sources like spirits to sleep, or any other intelligent trickery that traps the spirits into a state where they do not know what is happening to them could be starters. Or there could be another way that the readers know in relation to taming the spirits.

Edit: a lot comments are on the limits of magical system. Let me rephrase it. I like the idea proposed below of attaching the souls to a vessel or something similar and then they will be under the control of the humans. What could be the ideas to be kept in mind to attract the souls and attach them to a vessel from whereon they will be someone else's property rather than the dark lord??

Comment: What about using mirrors.. You could surround the place with polished shields etc and reflect light on them.. making the retreat into shadow. Or you could summon a dense fog that would blanket the whole area.

Comment: this is entirely opinion based since you are asking about use of magic, but you specify no rules for magic (unlike laws of physics, which are commonly known.)

Comment: Keep in mind that the [tag:magic] tag specifically asks you to define your magic system. Without that detail, we can't answer the question of how to deal with a presumably metaphysical entity using magical means. Barring an edit to address the details of your magic system and what a spirit is, this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: Send the army of undead (well, zombies, they are ubiquitous these days). The undead have no soul, so the spirits will find a physical vessel in them. As soon as they have all uploaded, you have them captured.

Comment: Welcome to WB.SE, Mukul!  Please be aware that our goal is to help you build your world (its rules and manifestation), not your story (what people do in your world).  In other words, we can help you design the rules that define your spirits (afterwhich you can write the plot about overcoming them), but we can't help you write the plot itself.

Comment: Based on the inputs and my line of thought I need help in building a world with requirements to neutralize the souls rather than annihilate them. Since these things are souls/spirits it is very much possible to attach them onto something that can give them a sense of completion. This attracting vessel or point of vessel can then be manipulated any which way and the spirits will follow in a trance. What is the apparatus to be used for such a deed? Or a religious/spiritual cue?? I don't want to keep it bland by using a magical spell unless there are garve challenges in achieving the spell.

Answer (score 1):

**Relocate the city.**

[image: relocating city]
https://gizmodo.com/moving-mountains-six-cities-and-towns-that-were-comple-1436927345

Spirits - who knows how you can affect them?  They are freaky!  But they are probably attached to unholy ground because your city is built on a cursed graveyard.

Let the spirits be.  Get all the stuff you want from the city (e.g. buildings, people, that statue of you) and move it all to a safe new site.  Let the spirits spirit around their unholy ground.  If there are some old buildings you don't care to move, leave them be.  The spirits can haunt them and it will keep them busy.